# Javascript click event take place only after javascript has completely driven

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, click

I have javascript in my page and I use there the click event. The problem is that in ie the clicking doesnt't hapen right away, but only after the hole javascript has gone through.
Then it fires that click event!

I would need it to hapen right away, **before**  the other javascript-code!

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // sorting the list
    var myLink = document.getElementById('header3');
    myLink.click();

    // scrolling the list to where the modified row is
    if ('${rowId}') {
        var row = $('#row-${rowId}');
        row.addClass("highlight");

        var scrollParent = ((jQuery.browser.msie) ? row.parent().parent().parent()[0] : row.parent()[0]);
        row[0].scrollIntoView(false);
        if (scrollParent.scrollTop > 0)
            scrollParent.scrollTop = scrollParent.scrollTop + (scrollParent.clientHeight / 2);
    }
}
```

That sorting should happen before scrolling! In ie the clicking happens **after** scrolling and then the scrolling is in wrong place.
In Firefox this works!

Can you help me on this?

Comment: what is the click doing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (never a good thing) that the code that is executing before the click event code is the code you enter here below the click() call, why don't you refactor that to a function and make it part of the code that happens when you call the click() code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Place your code in a separate function and trigger that function within the click.

```
 $(function(){
  function yourfunction(event) 
{

       //code to be executed after the click
       // scrolling the list to where the modified row is
      if ('${rowId}') {
                            var row = $('#row-${rowId}');
                            row.addClass("highlight");
                            var scrollParent = ((jQuery.browser.msie) ? row.parent().parent().parent()[0] : row.parent()[0]);
                             row[0].scrollIntoView(false);
                           if (scrollParent.scrollTop > 0)
                           scrollParent.scrollTop = scrollParent.scrollTop + (scrollParent.clientHeight / 2);
                      }

   return false;
  }

  });

   $(document).ready(function() { 
         // sorting the list
         $('#header3').click(yourfunction);
    });
```

Hope it helps,
Cumps